# How do movie channels get movies to be in HD if they've not been released on an HD source?

Tags: distribution

I just got a copy of the Twilight Time edition of Christine and the colors are a lot more vibrant than the other versions released on DVD. I believe Twilight Time was the first Blu-ray release of Christine. So how do cable channels get a DVD-like transfer and put it in HD? Yes, the aspect ratio is off, but I believe that's the only difference.

Comment: Adding someting to Paulie_D's comment. Sometimes old(er) shows get remastered in HD, digital remastering can do some improvements to colour and tone.

Comment: Your title and your question do not line up. You ask about how channels obtain a HD version, while you yourself talk about a Blu-ray (from 2013!). What does one thing have to do with another? And then you continue to talk both in general ("how do cable channels get a DVD-like transfer and put it in HD") and yet also specific ("Yes, the aspect ratio is off, but I believe that's the only difference.").

Comment: Cable channels don't go out and buy retail copies in order to show movies.

Comment: I would like to add that I saw it on cable back in 2011, before the TT release was out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Taking [***Christine***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085333/technical) as an example the original film format was 35mm which is, essentially, *better* than HD quality.

> Film is analog so there are no real "pixels." However, based on converted measures, a 35mm frame has 3 to 12 million pixels, depending on the stock, lens, and shooting conditions. An HD frame has 2 million pixels, measured using 1920 x 1080 scan lines. With this difference, 35mm appears vastly superior to HD.
>
> <sup>[**Source**](http://filmschoolonline.com/sample_lessons/sample_lesson_HD_vs_35mm.htm)</sup>

In this case TT have obtained a *newly-mastered* transfer of the 35mm film in HD format from Columbia-Sony

> Christine is presented on Blu-ray courtesy of Twilight Time with an AVC encoded 1080p transfer in 2.39:1. Columbia-Sony continues to provide exceptional looking high definition masters to Twilight Time
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://www.blu-ray.com/movies/Christine-Blu-ray/19650/)</sup>

Basically, the original release may not have been in HD ( not available in 1983) but with 35mm film a *new* HD master can be obtained any time.

Comment: exactly this.  people forget how big movie screens are and how good the film quality has to be to look good blown up to that size

Comment: As opposed to television shows from that period, which were often shot in video quality (with exceptions like Star Trek: The Next Generation, shot in 35mm and downscaled for video).